# MVC Authentication bypass for a single controller/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC with forms authentication and i need authentication bypass for one of my controllers, is it possible to bypass authentication for Cotroller(s)/Action(s).
I have been through [ASP.NET MVC Forms authentication and unauthenticated controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816625/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-and-unauthenticated-controller-actions) , but i dont want to restrict any action for a user/role , i want to allow it anonymously.

Can anyone help in this regard.

Comment: the Base Controller solution in the last answer seems to solve your issue

Comment: @Nicholas - That option can be adopted when you start a project, on a completed project changing all controllers is a risk i would not like to take. Thanks anyways for the helping hand.

Comment: No, I did a workaround, I split the application into two MVC apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The location tag solution posted on the page you [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816625/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-and-unauthenticated-controller-actions/1816726#1816726)  actually does work for MVC. The authorization controls around that kick in before the MVC framework has a chance to handle the request:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="~/MyAnonymousController">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Also note that you can put web.config files in sub-directories in your app. So for example, you can put your anonymous-access controller in it's own sub-directory and add a web.config in that directory with a location tag to allow anonymous access to everything in that directory: [Web.config: Wildcards in location and authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375208/web-config-wildcards-in-location-and-authorization)

Comment: The solution is quite good, but its late enough to be implemented now, thanks anywayz for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the following blog, it worked for me:

http://blog.tomasjansson.com/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application

Comment: thanks, but if you go through the question, its almost 2 years old now,and the solution you posted is one year old and in a different MVC version,anywayz thanks for help.

Comment: Also, don't post link-only answers.

Comment: The link Satpal posted is exactly the solution I was looking for just now, so I'm ok with a link-only answer in this case.